# Magento - moving blocks

Tags: magento

I am looking at creating a bundle product, that has several bundle items available to it.

My min problem, is that one item, is a checkbox list and has approx 200 options available.

So I'm looking to move this block from the right column, to the main column.

Does anyone know which file this is in?

I'm using v1.6.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firt step to move this block is locate where the block is add in template layot. To locate it  you can active frontend hint in system->configuration( select mimimum scope website)->in the tag advanced->developed and depure
[image]

next you can see the template of your block. for example footer.phtm
[image]

next you should search the definition of this block in the layout file. Layout file is a file.xml for compose your design.
in the example of footer:

```
<default>
     <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Footer</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
                </block>

    </default><!--handle default-->
```

Your block content in a left block probably, you should cut and paste the block in the content block to see this in the content block. 
hope help you.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. The problem I'm having though is locating the correct code for the bundle. There's code in a bundle.xml file and also a reference in catalog.xml I'm not sure what part of the code I'm moving.

Comment: try two options in development enviroment, and look the change.

Comment: Do you know which block im moving? In bundle.xml there is no reference to where the bundle information is displayed, whilst in catalog.xml, there are several references. I'm just unsure which one I need to move. Whenever I try, I get a blank page

Comment: i don´t know the block that you want to move. I show you how to move a block. The next step if to know why you get blanck page!! is don´t usual.

Comment: Ok, so I managed to narrow down that the `$this->getChildChildHtml('container', '', true, true)` was the problem. I moved this to the right part of the `view.phtml` file and all is ok. Many thanks. I will accept your answer as you have been very helpful