# Not able to modify product page layout

Tags: magento

I'm trying to modyfiy magento's product page layout (`app/design/frontend/default/*template*/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`) but i'm not able to do it. No matter what i'll change in `view.phtml`, changes are not visible. In `product/`, there are four .phtml files:

- list.phtml
- media.phtml
- price.phtml
- view.phtml

And it's impossible to modify only `media.phtml` and `view.phtml`, `list.phtml` and `price.html` edits works fine. I've tried to change `catalog.xml` to check if changes will be visible in frontend and yes - they are. I'm able to hide any block from this file. Have you any ideas or clues what can i do to modify product page? Any help would be appreciated.

---

## Solution

I had EasyTabs module installed and the file i needed to edit was `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/easytabs/catalogproductview.phtml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need active de frontend hints to know that the truthly you have been taking the correct template for the corresponding block. However, you can create a new template and asign in the correcpondient layout.xml for your custom phtml.
For example:

in catalog.xml

```
<block type="same type of the original lock" name="custom.name" template="your_template" ../>
```

Comment: yes, i have this line in my `catalog.xml` and it points to `catalog/product/view.phtml`. What's interesting - if i'll change `template` argument value to something unexisting, the frontend product page still works and looks exactly the same.

Comment: what is the father block of your block?? is a structural block??? content?? rigth??left???.if aren´t a estructural block, you need made a $this->getchildHtml('name') in your phtml block container. you have any type of cache??? can you active frontend hints ??

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm a bit magento newbie and i'm not sure what exactly you mean but here is a product view part from `catalog.xml`: http://pastebin.com/yQEuLGSz (please take a look at line 19 - i've changed file name to `view2.phtml` which don't exist and website is still working). According to cache - no, all cache engines are turned off, also the default magentos one

Comment: you need active frontend hint to see the template loaded. Do you know how active this?? you can visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822758/magento-moving-blocks/8827416#8827416 in this question i explain how to active

Comment: yes that helped me a lot, thank you! Previous developer installed `easytabs` module, that's the cause of all of those problems :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Admin->System->Configuration->Design->Theme` and if it all doesn't have `default` or is blank then you are using a custom theme.  If you're using a custom theme and you don't see it listed here then you should add it.

For more information you can read about the Magento Theme Hierarchy and fallback.

Comment: my current settings looks like that but i'm not sure what does it actually mean ;) http://i.imgur.com/YpEWA.jpg

Comment: Put `customtheme` in `Templates`, `Skin (Images / CSS)` and `Layout`, save and try your edits again.

Comment: That's assuming that `customtheme` is the name of your template:  `/app/design/frontend/default/customtheme/`

Comment: Can you send a screen shot of what your `/app/design/frontend/default/` folder structure looks like?

Comment: It looks ok as long as you have the same file structure as `default`.  You should turn on Template Hints as @davidselo suggested in his answer.  That will show you the exact files that are being pulled.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have installed extensions? I installed EasyTabs and if i want to change my Productview i have to edit an other templatefile than the view.phtml

Comment: this question is **resolved** but yes, i had easytabs installed and the file i needed to edit was `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/easytabs/catalogproductview.phtml`